# css - How to set fixed width of div that is display:inline

Tags: css, html

I want to set fixed width to my div that is set as `display:inline` without using `float` because it ruins my layout. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to set a width for an element with `display:inline`.

Try using: `display: inline-block`.

Comment: So why don't you consider to mark the answer as accepted? It'll help others to quickly find the answer. :)